# Unfair coin probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

We consider a mystery coin that lands „tails” with probability $\alpha$ and „heads” with probability $1 - \alpha$ . We define a random variable that represents the outcome of flipping the coin, with domain {0,1}.C is 1 if the coin lands „tails” and C is 0 if the coin lands „heads”.

a. Prove that the probability distribution of random variable is defined by equation: $P(C=c|\alpha) = \alpha ^ {c} (1 - \alpha)^{1 - c}$

b. Determine the probability that we obtain „heads” exactly twice at the first three tosses, if we know the value of $\alpha$.

c. Determine the probability that that we obtain „tails” exactly twice at the first three tosses, if we do not know the value of $\alpha$.

What I tried :

a) Is immediate from the properties of a binomial random variable.
I don't see what the difference between b) and c) is.

For b) we find $ p  = {3 \choose 2} \alpha ^2 (1-\alpha) $ and similarly for c).

Not sure why knowing or not knowing the value of $\alpha$ changes the probability.

Comment: Do we have a probability distribution for $\alpha$, say a pdf $f_\alpha(\mathscr a)$?  Let $C_n$ be the count of „tails” among $n$ tosses. Then we could say the "probability of $C_3=2$ with $\alpha$ unknown" would be marginal probability for $C_3=2$: $$\mathsf P(C_3=2)=\int_0^1 \mathsf P(C_3=2\mid \alpha=\mathscr a)\,f_\alpha(\mathscr a)\,\mathrm d\mathscr a$$

Comment: PS: (b) The probability for obtaining „**heads**” exactiy twice among three tosses is the probability for obtaining „tails” exactly once. So since $\alpha$ is the probability that a coin flip lands tails: $$\mathsf P(C_3=1\mid \alpha) = \binom 31 \alpha\,(1-\alpha)^2$$